# What is the default data type of number in C?

Tags: c, overflow

In C,

```
unsigned int size = 1024*1024*1024*2;
```

which results a warning "integer overflow in expression..."
While

```
unsigned int size = 2147483648;
```

results no warning?

Is the right value of the first expression is default as int? Where does it mention in C99 spec?

Comment: Are you sure the second value is not [`2147483648`](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=1024*1024*1024*2&rlz=1C1GIGM_enIN617IN617&oq=1024*1024*1024*2&aqs=chrome..69i57.1172j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: You probably meant the value `2147483648`. My answer assumes this.

Comment: Had been fixd! Thanks!

Comment: The root of the problem is to not realize that integer constants have a type too, just like named variables.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When using a decimal constant without any suffixes the type of the decimal constant is the first that can be represented, in order (the current C standard, 6.4.4 Constants p5):

- int
- long int
- long long int

The type of the first expression is `int`, since every constant with the value 1024 and 2 can be represented as int. The computation of those constants will be done in type int, and the result will overflow.

Assuming INT_MAX equals 2147483647 and LONG_MAX is greater than 2147483647, the type of the second expression is `long int`, since this value cannot be represented as int, but can be as long int. If INT_MAX equals LONG_MAX equals 2147483647, then the type is `long long int`.

Comment: Unless INT_MAX == LONG_MAX, in which case, the second expression is probably of type `long long int`.  Note that Win64 is a 64-bit environment where INT_MAX == LONG_MAX; most 32-bit environments run with INT_MAX == LONG_MAX.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you. Yes those are common limits, I should have remembered that.

Answer (score 4):

```
unsigned int size = 1024*1024*1024*2;
```

This expression `1024*1024*1024*2` (in the expression `1024` and `2` are of type `signed int`) produces result that is of type `signed int` and this value is too big for `signed int` . Therefore, you get the warning.

After that signed multiplication it is assigned to `unsigned int` .

Comment: i know that value is overflow for signed int. But why it is signed int?

Comment: @mingpepe Because  by default `1024` and `2` are signed integers , so multiplication result is also of type `signed int` and then the type is changed when assigned to `unsigned int` .

Comment: The product `1024*1024*1024*2` overflows and `int` overflow is UB.  Better to use `1024u*1024*1024*2`