# Floating Point Representation in Hexadecimal using C Langauge

Tags: c, floating-point, hex

I typed the following C code:

```
typedef unsigned char* byte_pointer;

void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, size_t len) 
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
  printf(" %.2x", start[i]);
  printf("\n");
}

 void show_float(float x) 
  {
       show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(float));
  }
 void main()
    {
         float f = 3.9;
         show_float(f);
    }
```

The output of this code is:
Output: 0x4079999A

**Manual Calculations**
1.1111001100110011001100 x 2 power 1

M: 1111001100110011001100

E: 1 + 127 = 128(d) = 10000000(b)

Final Bits: **01000000011110011001100110011000**

Hex: 0x40799998

Why this last A is displayed despite of 8.

Comment: What happens if you have `float f = 3.9f;` ? Your `3.9` is a `double` value. Note that 3.9 cannot be converted exactly to finite binary floating point representation, so the implementation details will cover whether the approximation is a round-up or a round-down.

Comment: Better not to `typedef` pointers.

Comment: @WeatherVane: it should not change much. The truncation to float of the double 3.9 value is likely to be the float value 3.9f. I would assume that the representation in multi-precision should be `0x4079999999999...`. And that is normally rounded to the closer representable floating point value which is `0x4079999A`. The question is which *manual calculation* could lead to `0x40799998`...

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes in practice I found no difference. A deleted comment queried the basis of the manual calculation ;)

Comment: 3.9
3d   = 11b
Decimal Portion
0.9 x 2=1.8 1
0.8 x 2=1.6 1
0.6 x 2=1.2 1
0.2 x 2=0.4 0
0.4 x 2=0.8 0
0.8 x 2=1.6 1
0.6 x 2=1.2 1
0.2 x 2=0.4 0
0.4 x 2=0.8 0
0.8 x 2=1.6 1
0.6 x 2=1.2 1
0.2 x 2=0.4 0
0.4 x 2=0.8 0
0.8 x 2=1.6 1
0.6 x 2=1.2 1
0.2 x 2=0.4 0
0.4 x 2=0.8 0
0.8 x 2=1.6 1
0.6 x 2=1.2 1
0.2 x 2=0.4 0
0.4 x 2=0.8 0
Decimal String: 11.111001100110011001100 (truncated)
= 1.1111001100110011001100 x 2power1 (normalizaed)
S: 0
M: 1111001100110011001100
E: 1 + 127 = 128(d)
= 10000000(b)
Final Bits: 01000000011110011001100110011000
Hex: 0x40799998

Comment: @Hafeez don't m put lengthy clarifications in a comment, as you can see it's pretty unreadable. Instead [edit] your question and put all clarifications __into the question__.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Just FYI, [the shortest decimal numeral that differs when converted first to a `double` and then a `float` has seven significant digits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65142790/298225), and there is only one of them, except for the sign.

Answer (score 1):

> As per manual calculations the answer in Hex should supposed to be: Output: 0x40799998

Those undisclosed manual calculations must be wrong. The correct result is 4079999A<sub>16</sub>.

In the format commonly used for `float`, IEEE-754 binary32 or “single precision,” numbers are represented as an integer with magnitude less than 224 multiplied by a power of two within certain limits. (The floating-point representation is often described in other forms, such as sign, a 24-digit binary significand with radix point after the first digit, and a power of two. These forms are mathematically equivalent.)

The two numbers in this form closest to 3.9 are 16,357,785•2<sup>−23</sup> and 16,357,786•2<sup>−23</sup>. These are, respectively, 3.8999998569488525390625 and 3.900000095367431640625. Lining them up, we can see the latter is closer to 3.9:

```
3.8999998569488525390625
3.9000000000000000000000
3.9000000953674316406250
```

as the former differs by 1.5 at the seventh digit after the decimal point, whereas the latter differs by about 9.5 at the eighth digit after the decimal point.

Therefore, the best conversion of 3.9 to this `float` format produces 16,357,786•2<sup>−23</sup>. In hexadecimal, 16,357,786 is F9999A<sub>16</sub>. In the encoding of the representation into the bits of a `float`, the low 23 bits of the significand are put into the primary significand field. The low 23 bits are 79999A<sub>16</sub>, and that is what we should see in the primary significand field.

Also note we can easily see the binary for 3.9 is
**11.1110011001100110011001**1001100110011001100110…<sub>2</sub>. The bold marks the 24 bits that fit in the `float` significand. Immediately after them is 1001…, which we can see ought to round up, since it exceeds half of the previous bit, and therefore the last four bits of the significand should be 1010.

(Also note that good C implementations convert numerals in source text to the nearest representable number, especially for numbers without many decimal digits, but the C standard does not require this. It says “For decimal floating constants, and also for hexadecimal floating constants when `FLT_RADIX` is not a power of 2, the result is either the nearest representable value, or the larger or smaller representable value immediately adjacent to the nearest representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner. However, the encoding shown in the question 40799998<sub>16</sub>, is not for either of the adjacent representable values, 40799999<sub>16</sub> and 4079999A<sub>16</sub>. It is farther away than either.)